# Not able to access API due to CORS issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-5.0, openiddict

With Asp.Net Core 5 and [OpenIdDict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for OpenId I have 3 apps:

```
Auth with OpenIdDict running on https://localhost:5000
API running on https://localhost:5001
SPA running on https://localhost:5002
```

From my Angular's SPA I am able to login and logout.

I am able to access API endpoints that allow anonymous access.

If I try to access an API endpoint that requires authentication without sending the Access Token I get an 401 error as expected.

**Problem**

When I try to access an API endpoint that requires authentication and send the Access Token in the Authorisation Header I get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5001/v1.0/posts' from origin 'https://localhost:5002' has been blocked by CORS policy: 

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

POST https://localhost:5001/v1.0/posts
```

**UPDATE**

Just in case my Angular request is:

```
httpClient.post(`https://localhost:5001/v1.0/posts`, 
 { title: "My post", body: "Some text" }, 
 { headers: { 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
     'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.access_token}` 
   } 
 }).subscribe();
```

The **API Startup's** `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods are:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

  services
    .AddControllers()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
    .AddJsonOptions()
    .AddFluentValidation();

  services
    .AddApiVersioning(x => {
      x.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(x);
      x.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
      x.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
      x.ReportApiVersions = true;
      x.RouteConstraintName = "version";
    });

  services.AddDbContext<Context>(x =>
    x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get<Options>().Database.Connection, y => {
      y.MigrationsHistoryTable("__Migrations");
      y.UseNetTopologySuite();
    }).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(Environment.IsDevelopment())
      .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll));

  services.AddRouting(x => { x.AppendTrailingSlash = false; x.LowercaseUrls = true; });

  services.AddCors(x => {
    x.AddPolicy("Cors", y => 
      y.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:5002").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    });

  services.AddAuthentication(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

  services
    .AddAuthorization(x => {
      x.AddPolicy(Policy.Admin, y => y.RequireClaim("Admin"));
    });

  services
    .AddIdentityCore<User>(x => x.AddDefaultOptions())
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(x => {
      x.SetIssuer("https://localhost:5000");
      x.AddAudiences("api");
      x.UseIntrospection();
      x.SetClientId("api").SetClientSecret("test");
      x.UseSystemNetHttp();
      x.UseAspNetCore();
    });

  services.AddHsts();
  services.AddHttpsRedirection();

  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));

  services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(x => {
    x.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = false;
    x.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    x.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context => new InvalidModelStateResponseFactory(context).GetResponse();
  });

  services.Configure<Options>(Configuration);

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment environment) {

  application.UseHsts();
  application.UseHttpsRedirection();

  application.UseRouting();
  application.UseCors("Cors");

  application.UseAuthentication();
  application.UseAuthorization();

  application.UseEndpoints(x => {
    x.MapControllers();
  });

}
```

The **Auth Startup's** `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods are:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

  services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
    .AddJsonOptions()
    .AddFluentValidation();

  services.AddRouting(x => { x.AppendTrailingSlash = false; x.LowercaseUrls = true; });

  services.AddCors(x => {
    x.AddPolicy("Cors", y => 
      y.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001", "https://localhost:5002").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    });

  services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => {

    x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get<Options>().Database.Connection, y => {
      y.MigrationsHistoryTable("__Migrations");
      y.UseNetTopologySuite();  
    }).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(Environment.IsDevelopment())
      .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);

    x.UseOpenIddict<Data.Entities.Application, Authorization, Scope, Token, Int32>();

  });

  services
    .AddIdentityCoreWithAuthentication<User>(x => x.AddDefaultOptions())
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserConfirmation<UserConfirmation<User>>();

  services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
    x.AccessDeniedPath = "/denied";
    x.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    x.Cookie.Name = "auth";
    x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
    x.LoginPath = "/login";
    x.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    x.SlidingExpiration = true;
  });

  services.AddOpenIddict()
  
    .AddCore(x => {

      x.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
       .UseDbContext<Context>()
       .ReplaceDefaultEntities<Data.Entities.Application, Authorization, Scope, Token, Int32>();
    
    })

    .AddServer(x => {

      x.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
       .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
       .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
       .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect")
       .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

      x.RegisterClaims(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role);

      x.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);
      
      x.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

  x.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate().AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

      x.UseAspNetCore()
       .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
       .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();

    })

    .AddValidation(x => {
      x.UseLocalServer();
      x.UseAspNetCore();
    });

  services.AddHsts();
  services.AddHttpsRedirection();

  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));

  services.Configure<Options>(Configuration);

  services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

} 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IWebHostEnvironment environment) {

  application.UseHsts();
  application.UseHttpsRedirection();

  application.UseStaticFiles();

  application.UseRouting();
  application.UseCors("Cors");

  application.UseAuthentication();
  application.UseAuthorization();

  application.UseEndpoints(x => {
    x.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
  });

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've been trying a lot but always the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you wrote should be correct.

Initially I had many issues with CORS too. Finally I found out that the order of `app.UseXXX` is essential. To use CORS it is important to call `UseCors` **after** `UseRouting` and **before** `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization`

```
app.UseRouting(...);
app.UseCors(...);
app.UseAuthentication(...);
app.UseAuthorization(...);
```

Comment: I have exactly that sequence in both API and AUTH applications

Comment: Ensure that the code of the app that calls the API calls the https, and not http url? Even if you are using http-redirection that might not work

Comment: Yes, I have HTTPS on all my requests. This is really strange because before I login I am able to access an Endpoint that does not requires authentication such as `https://localhost:5001/news` ... After I login if I call that endpoint without the `Authorization` header I'm ok ... If I add the `Authorisation` header I get the CORS error.

Comment: Have you listed your application url in your OpenIdDict's client Cors Orgins?

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer I am not sure I understood your question. You mean, if I listed my SPA Client application running on `https://localhost:5002` in `AddCors` method? Yes, I have `AllowAnyOrigin` in there. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MiguelMoura can you try .AllowCredentials? But then, in production environemnt do not use AllowAnyOrigin, but specify the endpoint.

Comment: @MichaelMairegger Yes, I also added AllowCredentials and needed to specify the Origins as AllowCredentials does not work with AnyOrigin. I just added an UPDATE to my question with all code from API and AUTH apps's Configure and ConfigureServices. I have been trying to figure this out changing a few things including the order but I get always the same result. Probably is some detail I am missing ...

Comment: @A.Hasemeyer  I just added an UPDATE to my question with all code from API and AUTH apps's Configure and ConfigureServices. Can you spot something wrong?

Comment: The Cors Origin is not something you will have in code, it is a configuration for the Client on your Authority Server. In your Authority's database when you register your SPA App as a Client there should be a table called ClientCorsOrigins, or something along those lines as I am familiar with IS4 not OpenIdDict. But you will need to register your SPAs URL in that database to pass the CORS policy.